# Porting DXUT SDKMesh to import OBJ files, where to add texture coordinates and indices?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, directx-11, direct3d

Good afternoon,

I've successfully ported DXUT SDKMesh to load imported obj files through TinyOBJ loader https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader) to draw Mesh using correct indices values.

I also added a texture which is loaded as a DDS material

It currently draws the mesh but the entire texture is stretched over each triangle

I now need to figure out where to add the texture coordinates, and the indices for those texture coordinates.

The code was reconstructed from DXUT SDKMesh `CDXUTSDKMesh::CreateFromMemory` function. The SDKMesh code is rather large file, but it can be found here for reference http://freesourcecode.net/cprojects/92957/sourcecode/SDKmesh.cpp

As you can see, I'm loading the list of vertices using `InitData.pSysMem = &vertex_buffer[0];`

And the list of indices using `InitData2.pSysMem = &index_buffer[0];`

The DXUT SDKMesh does the same thing with a binary .sdkmesh file 
And I'm simultaneously loading the DXUT sample model tiny.sdkmesh. They are both rendered using the same shaders and render functions. So I know the problem is not in the render function, but rather its in the way I construct the vertex and index buffers.

What I need to know is how these vertex and index buffers are constructed. And
I understand this is dictated by the vertex shader, although I don't exactly know how.

The vertex shader has these inputs and outputs:

```
struct VS_INPUT
{
float4 vPosition    : POSITION;
float3 vNormal      : NORMAL;
float2 vTexcoord    : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
float3 vNormal      : NORMAL;
float2 vTexcoord    : TEXCOORD0;
float4 vPosition    : SV_POSITION;
};
```

If I leave the values commented as they are now, it works. If I add them, it breaks the model.

What I don't understand is how to group the vertices and texcoords into one buffer and vertex_index and texcoord_index into another. And how this is broken up and loaded as vertex shader input. (if it even is used this way).

I tried adding them sequentially, one after another, etc, in each case it broke the model.

If you have any advice or education on how to properly put these together, your help is appreciated. Thank you,

```
//Need to sort indices and vertices from TinyOBJ loader
std::vector<float> vertex_buffer;
for (int i = 0; i < num_vertices/3; i++)
{
    vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.vertices[i * 3 + 0]);
    vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.vertices[i * 3 + 1]);
    vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.vertices[i * 3 + 2]);
    //vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.texcoords[i * 2 + 0]);
    //vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.texcoords[i * 2 + 1]);
    //vertex_buffer.push_back(0);
}

std::vector<UINT> index_buffer;
for (int i = 0; i < num_indices/3; i++)
{
    index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i * 3 + 0].vertex_index);
    index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i * 3 + 1].vertex_index);
    index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i * 3 + 2].vertex_index);
    //index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i * 2 + 0].texcoord_index);
    //index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i * 2 + 1].texcoord_index);
    //index_buffer.push_back(0);
}

g_Mesh11.m_ppVertices = (BYTE**)&vertex_buffer;
g_Mesh11.m_ppIndices = (BYTE**)&index_buffer;

//Magic Numbers that make it use every vertex and index
int vertexes_size = (vertex_buffer.size()) * sizeof(float) *1.5F;
int indexes_size = shapes[0].mesh.indices.size() * sizeof(UINT) *3;

//Set Vertex Buffer Array
g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray = new SDKMESH_MESH;
g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_VERTEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0] = 0;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
bufferDesc.ByteWidth = (UINT)(vertexes_size);
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
InitData.pSysMem = &attrib.vertices[0];
dxCtr->m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &InitData, &g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].pVB11);
g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].StrideBytes = 12;
g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].SizeBytes = vertexes_size;

//Set Index Buffer array
g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer = 0;
g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_INDEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].IndexType = IT_32BIT;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc2;
bufferDesc2.ByteWidth = (UINT)(indexes_size);
bufferDesc2.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bufferDesc2.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
bufferDesc2.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
bufferDesc2.MiscFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData2;
InitData2.pSysMem = &index_buffer[0]; 
dxCtr->m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &InitData2, &g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].pIB11);
g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].SizeBytes = indexes_size;

//Set subset
SDKMESH_SUBSET v_subset;
//v_subset.Name = "Base";
v_subset.MaterialID = 0;
v_subset.PrimitiveType = PT_TRIANGLE_LIST;
v_subset.IndexCount = num_indices;
v_subset.VertexCount = num_vertices;
v_subset.VertexStart = 0;
v_subset.IndexStart = 0;
g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets = new UINT;
g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets[0] = 0;
g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].NumSubsets = 1;
g_Mesh11.m_pSubsetArray = new SDKMESH_SUBSET;
g_Mesh11.m_pSubsetArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets[0]] = v_subset;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it, I don't know why exactly it works like this but

the index buffer has to be 0 for Texcoords

```
bool LoadOBJ(std::string object_file)
{
    TinyObjLoader::LoadOBJ(object_file);

    g_Mesh11.m_pMaterialArray = new SDKMESH_MATERIAL;
    std::wstring strPath = L"Media\\Base_skin.dds";
    if (FAILED(DXUTGetGlobalResourceCache().CreateTextureFromFile(dxCtr->m_pDevice, dxCtr->m_pImmediateContext, strPath.c_str(), &g_Mesh11.m_pMaterialArray->pDiffuseRV11,true)))
        g_Mesh11.m_pMaterialArray->pDiffuseRV11 = (ID3D11ShaderResourceView*)ERROR_RESOURCE_VALUE;

    SDKMESH_SUBSET* pSubset = nullptr;
    D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY PrimType;

    struct T_Vertex
    {
        float vX;
        float vY;
        float vZ;
        float nX;
        float nY;
        float nZ;
        float tX;
        float tY;
        UINT vXIndex;
        UINT vYIndex;
        UINT vZIndex;
        UINT nXIndex;
        UINT nYIndex;
        UINT nZIndex;
        UINT tXIndex;
        UINT tYIndex;
    };

    std::vector<T_Vertex> temp_vertices;
    size_t index_offset = 0;
    for (size_t f = 0; f < shapes[0].mesh.num_face_vertices.size(); f++) {
        int fv = shapes[0].mesh.num_face_vertices[f];
        // Loop over vertices in the face.
        for (size_t v = 0; v < fv; v++) {
            // access to vertex
            tinyobj::index_t idx = shapes[0].mesh.indices[index_offset + v];
            T_Vertex temp_vertex;
            temp_vertex.vX = attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 0];
            temp_vertex.vY = attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 1];
            temp_vertex.vZ = attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 2];
            temp_vertex.nX = attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 0];
            temp_vertex.nY = attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 1];
            temp_vertex.nZ = attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 2];
            temp_vertex.tX = attrib.texcoords[2 * idx.texcoord_index + 0];
            temp_vertex.tY = attrib.texcoords[2 * idx.texcoord_index + 1];
            temp_vertex.vXIndex = 3 * idx.vertex_index + 0;
            temp_vertex.vYIndex = 3 * idx.vertex_index + 1;
            temp_vertex.vZIndex = 3 * idx.vertex_index + 2;
            temp_vertex.nXIndex = 3 * idx.normal_index + 0;
            temp_vertex.nYIndex = 3 * idx.normal_index + 1;
            temp_vertex.nZIndex = 3 * idx.normal_index + 2;
            temp_vertex.tXIndex = 3 * idx.texcoord_index + 0;
            temp_vertex.tYIndex = 3 * idx.texcoord_index + 1;
            temp_vertices.push_back(temp_vertex);
        }
        index_offset += fv;
    }

    std::vector<float> vertex_buffer;
    std::vector<UINT> index_buffer;

    for (auto& temp_vertex : temp_vertices)
    {
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vX);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vY);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vZ);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nX);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nY);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nZ);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.tX);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.tY);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(0);

        index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vXIndex);
        index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vYIndex);
        index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vZIndex);
        index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nXIndex);
        index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nYIndex);
        index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nZIndex);
        index_buffer.push_back(0);
        index_buffer.push_back(0);
        index_buffer.push_back(0);
    }

    int num_vertices = vertex_buffer.size();
    int num_indices = index_buffer.size();

    g_Mesh11.m_ppVertices = (BYTE**)&vertex_buffer;
    g_Mesh11.m_ppIndices = (BYTE**)&index_buffer;

    int vertexes_size = vertex_buffer.size() * sizeof(float);       int indexes_size = index_buffer.size() * sizeof(UINT);  
    //Set Vertex Buffer Array
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray = new SDKMESH_MESH;
    g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_VERTEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
    int t = g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0];
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0] = 0;
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = (UINT)(vertexes_size);
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    InitData.pSysMem = &vertex_buffer[0];
    dxCtr->m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &InitData, &g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].pVB11);
    g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].StrideBytes = 36;// 12;
    g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].SizeBytes = vertexes_size;

    //Set Index Buffer array
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer = 0;
    g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_INDEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
    g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].IndexType = IT_32BIT;
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc2;
    bufferDesc2.ByteWidth = (UINT)(indexes_size);
    bufferDesc2.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDesc2.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc2.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc2.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData2;
    InitData2.pSysMem = &index_buffer[0];
    dxCtr->m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc2, &InitData2, &g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].pIB11);
    g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].SizeBytes = indexes_size;

    //Set subset
    SDKMESH_SUBSET v_subset;
    v_subset.MaterialID = 0;
    v_subset.PrimitiveType = PT_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    v_subset.IndexCount = num_indices;
    v_subset.VertexCount = num_vertices;
    v_subset.VertexStart = 0;
    v_subset.IndexStart = 0;
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets = new UINT;
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets[0] = 0;
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].NumSubsets = 1;
    g_Mesh11.m_pSubsetArray = new SDKMESH_SUBSET;
    g_Mesh11.m_pSubsetArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets[0]] = v_subset;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to interleave the data into one Vertex Buffer. This will likely require duplicating vertices where say the position is the same, but the texture coordinates or normal differ.

```
struct Vertex
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 position;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 normal;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 textureCoordinate;
};

typedef std::unordered_multimap<UINT, UINT> VertexCache;

DWORD AddVertex(UINT hash, Vertex* pVertex, VertexCache& cache)
{
    auto f = cache.equal_range(hash);

    for (auto it = f.first; it != f.second; ++it)
    {
        auto& tv = vertices[it->second];

        if (0 == memcmp(pVertex, &tv, sizeof(Vertex)))
        {
            return it->second;
        }
    }

    DWORD index = static_cast<UINT>(vertices.size());
    vertices.emplace_back(*pVertex);

    VertexCache::value_type entry(hash, index);
    cache.insert(entry);
    return index;
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
// If a duplicate vertex doesn't exist, add this vertex to the Vertices
// list. Store the index in the Indices array. The Vertices and Indices
// lists will eventually become the Vertex Buffer and Index Buffer for
// the mesh.
DWORD index = AddVertex(vertexIndex, &vertex, vertexCache);
```

For a full implementation, see [WaveFrontReader.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/blob/master/Utilities/WaveFrontReader.h) and [meshconvert](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/blob/master/Meshconvert/Meshconvert.cpp) that come with the [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh) library.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in my case, I tried constructing the vertex buffer with 3 coordinates, 3 normals, and 2 texcoords, then having an index buffer just refer to each vertex as a whole. But it seems to want to have an index for each value, like index 0 for X coord, index 1 for Y coord, Index for Z coord. But I tinyobjloader seems to have per vertex 3 coordinates, 3 normal, and 3 texcoords, instead of 2. So Im trying to figure out how to read the data correctly

Comment: Also, this is really dumb, but tinyobj has a different number of vertices, normal, and texcoords. In this order texcoords<vertices<normal. But not in 2/3/3 ratios, more like 135000,150000,173000 for the model I import.

Comment: You have to duplicate the vertex data to get a single index buffer index for each vertex. You also can't split up semantics by component: you can have multiple VBs where one has the ``POSITION``, another has ``TEXCOORD``, etc. but you can't put the x-component of ``POSITION`` in one VB and the y-component in another VB. You also can't have different indices for each VB when doing multi-VB reads

Comment: Is this because the vertex buffer is split into chunks by stride and each chunk is sent to vertex shader?

Comment: No. All the data from al the vertex buffers is gathered at once and given to an instance of the VS. The stride just determines how many bytes each vertex entry in a given VB is skipped.